# Mysql Replication slave don't update master mysqld when master mysqld is up after down

Tags: mysql, replication, master-slave

i set up mysql replication, the set up goes like this master - slave , when master is up and slave is up the replication is fine. The problem arises when the master is down and i updated the slave (insert, update, delete) records, when the master is back online those update in slave do not replicated in master. Is there any way to update the master after it comes back from offline to online?

tnx

Comment: Don't write to the slave. Only write to master.

Comment: @RPM so in that case we cannot use slave msqld as back up server?

Comment: This is the correct behavior for a Master-Slave replication. You have to write to master, not slave. What you probably looking for is a Master-Master replication, where the server is a master and also a slave.

Comment: sorry for this newbie question, i'm new to mysql replication.